# How to create a react native app with javascript reactnative 0.72

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, npx

In new release they change the default language to ts, so when you run

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

you get a ts project. I want to have a javascript project.
How can I get a javascript project by using react-native init command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `--template` flag, like so: `npx react-native init AwesomeProject --template <template_name>`

And while I cannot recommend any JS templates, you shouldn't have a hard time finding any online. Remember that TS-by-default is there for a reason - it's an industry standard by now.